# How to add "Add to cart button" on custom product detail section?

Tags: magento-2.1, addtocart

I am working on custom Magento 2 site development. And I want to add the **add to cart button** on product view page.

Where there are 3 tabs i.e. Details, Reviews and Accessories/part.

I have created Accessories/Part content in phtml file in tabular format in which last column is "Add to Cart", and in that  **"Add to cart" button** is placed

So, **when user click on add to cart button** it should **add that product to cart**

How should I do this functionality? Can anyone help me by which way I can do it.

Comment: HI, @ashwin if the answer is help full please make as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

In your **block** file

```
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct;
<?php
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
         \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $listProductBlock,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->listProductBlock = $listProductBlock;
    }

public function getProductCollection()
{
    /** @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection */
   $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();
    return $collection;
}
public function getAddToCartPostParams($product)
{
    return $this->listProductBlock->getAddToCartPostParams($product);
}
?>
```

get **productlist** in view file

```
    <?php 
    const PARAM_NAME_BASE64_URL = 'r64';
    const PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED = 'uenc';
    use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action; 
   $_product=your product
        <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>
        <?php echo $_product->getName()?>
        <form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['action']; ?>" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data']['product']; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED; ?>" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED]; ?>">
            <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
            <?php $storeManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface'); ?>
                <button type="submit"
                        title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')); ?>"
                        class="action tocart primary">
                    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                </button>
        </form>
```